# how to install and use angularJS plugin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, plugins, dependency-injection

I wanted to use this angular-number-picker [plugin](https://github.com/leftstick/angular-number-picker) in my rails project.

I downloaded the .min.js file and the .js file and put the in the plugins folder. Then I also included the js in

/global_plugins.js

```
//= require global/plugins/angular-number-picker/angular-number-picker.min.js
```

and then I also inject it to the dependency of my app

/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('fotograft', ['ngResource', 'angular-loading-bar', 'cgBusy', 'ngFileUpload', 'MessageCenterModule', 'rails', 'Devise', 'google.places', 'ui.sortable','checklist-model', 
 'textAngular', 'angularMoment', '720kb.socialshare', 'ngSanitize', '720kb.tooltips', 'angular-md5', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'infinite-scroll', 'datatables', 'datatables.bootstrap', 
 'ngResource', 'frapontillo.bootstrap-switch', 'angular-bootstrap-select','angular-number-picker', 'angular-bootstrap-select.extra', 'ngTextTruncate', 'chart.js', 'timer', 'siyfion.sfTypeahead'])
```

The problem is when I tried to load any page, the page will not respond. So I tried to view the console and debug, the error was that

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/modulerr?
```

I truncated the rest of the error messages, because they are kind of long and look gibberish.

So, I would like to ask what am I missing here? I saw from the author's webpage that I need to include the src to the plugin in the html page, but I have no idea which page I should include it in.

Appreciate it if any rails and angularJS developer can help me out here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you double check the [link in the source code](https://github.com/leftstick/angular-number-picker) you provided, it looks like the module name that you have to register is supposed to be `angularNumberPicker` instead of `angular-number-picker`.

So you want your app.js module registry to look like this:

`var app = angular.module('fotograft', ['ngResource', 'angular-loading-bar', 'cgBusy', 'ngFileUpload', 'MessageCenterModule', 'rails', 'Devise', 'google.places', 'ui.sortable','checklist-model', 
 'textAngular', 'angularMoment', '720kb.socialshare', 'ngSanitize', '720kb.tooltips', 'angular-md5', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'infinite-scroll', 'datatables', 'datatables.bootstrap', 
 'ngResource', 'frapontillo.bootstrap-switch', 'angular-bootstrap-select','angularNumberPicker', 'angular-bootstrap-select.extra', 'ngTextTruncate', 'chart.js', 'timer', 'siyfion.sfTypeahead']);`

Comment: oh ya!. Thank you so much. I didn't know that. I was so careless.

Comment: Happens to the best of us!!!! If when in doubt and there isn't instructions you can always check the source code for the module and see what it's setter module name is also. (Incase its poorly documented)